# Equilibrium solutions of a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm suppose to find equilibrium solutions that satisfy the following system of differential equations:

> $$\frac{dx}{dt} = -3x+2y$$
>   $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 6x+y$$

This may be a simple question, but I feel like my instructor didn't explain *how* to go about this. All I know, if I'm even correct, is that we need to make sure that $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$. I am not interested in a linear algebra approach for this problem. I'm just looking for a simple explanation as to *how* to approach problems similar to the one I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, you need $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ to both be zero.
That means the right sides of the differential equations must be $0$ as well.  So you have a system of two equations in two unknowns to solve:
$$ \eqalign{-3x+2y &= 0\cr 6x+y &= 0\cr}$$

Comment: So $x=0 , y=0$ is our one and *only* equilibrium solution then.

Comment: Yes, that's right.